# WinUI3 self-contained application fails to run

Tags: xaml, winapi, winui-3

When I install the Runtime package from microsoft (as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/use-windows-app-sdk-run-time)) my unpackaged WinUI3 app runs correctly.

When I follow the instructions for a self-contained WinUI3 app (as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/package-and-deploy/self-contained-deploy/deploy-self-contained-apps)) I get a collection of files in the release folder which I extract to a separated directory from my app. This also includes Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.Bootstrap.dll which I LoadLibrary() and call MddBootstrapInitialize.

The same happens with the  SelfContained Deployment cpp-console-unpackaged sample  when I call the bootstrap found in that directory. The unpackaged sample does not call the bootstrap.

This time the call fails with ERROR_NOT_FOUND.

Do I have to do anything else in order to use the WinApp SDK as self-contained app?

```
'tp2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'F:\TP2Modules\Turbo Play WinUI3\Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.Insights.Resource.dll'. 
\BuildOutput\Release\x64\WindowsAppRuntime_DLL\WindowsAppRuntimeInsights.h(44)\Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.Bootstrap.dll!00007FFA0C6D16E5: (caller: 00007FFA0C6D14B6) LogHr(1) tid(4248) 8007029C An assertion failure has occurred.
\BuildOutput\Release\x64\WindowsAppRuntime_DLL\WindowsAppRuntimeInsights.h(44)\Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.Bootstrap.dll!00007FFA0C6D16E5: (caller: 00007FFA0C6D14B6) LogHr(2) tid(4248) 8007029C An assertion failure has occurred.
    Msg:[Failed to load resource string. id: 10001] 
'tp2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\AppXDeploymentClient.dll'. 
'tp2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Windows.ApplicationModel.dll'. 
\dev\WindowsAppRuntime_BootstrapDLL\MddBootstrap.cpp(814)\Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.Bootstrap.dll!00007FFA0C6CA677: (caller: 00007FFA0C6C8FEC) LogHr(3) tid(4248) 80040010 Object is not in any of the inplace active states
    Msg:[Bootstrap.Intitialize: Scanning packages for Major.Minor=1.3, Tag=, MinVersion=3000.820.152.0] CallContext:[\Initialize] 
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA6127536C (KernelBase.dll) in tp2.exe: WinRT originate error - 0x80070491 : 'There was no match for the specified key in the index.'.
\dev\WindowsAppRuntime_BootstrapDLL\MddBootstrap.cpp(943)\Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.Bootstrap.dll!00007FFA0C6CB323: (caller: 00007FFA0C6C8FEC) Exception(1) tid(4248) 80070491 There was no match for the specified key in the index.
    Msg:[Enumeration: Major.Minor=1.3, Tag=, MinVersion=3000.820.152.0] CallContext:[\Initialize] 
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA6127536C in tp2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: wil::ResultException at memory location 0x0000003C1912AB30.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA6127536C in tp2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x0000000000000000.
\dev\WindowsAppRuntime_BootstrapDLL\MddBootstrap.cpp(213)\Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.Bootstrap.dll!00007FFA0C6DBFF1: (caller: 00007FFA0C6C71E9) ReturnHr(1) tid(4248) 80070491 There was no match for the specified key in the index.
    Msg:[\dev\WindowsAppRuntime_BootstrapDLL\MddBootstrap.cpp(943)\Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.Bootstrap.dll!00007FFA0C6CB323: (caller: 00007FFA0C6C8FEC) Exception(1) tid(4248) 80070491 There was no match for the specified key in the index.
    Msg:[Enumeration: Major.Minor=1.3, Tag=, MinVersion=3000.820.152.0] CallContext:[\Initialize] 
] CallContext:[\Initialize] 
\dev\WindowsAppRuntime_BootstrapDLL\MddBootstrap.cpp(166)\Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.Bootstrap.dll!00007FFA0C6C72E6: (caller: 00007FF97F7A9440) ReturnHr(2) tid(4248) 80070491 There was no match for the specified key in the index.
    CallContext:[\Initialize]
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce using the SelfContained Deployment [cpp-console-unpackaged](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK-Samples/tree/main/Samples/SelfContainedDeployment/cpp-console-unpackaged) sample and [the Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/tutorial-unpackaged-deployment?tabs=cpp).

Comment: Source code is [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/blob/main/dev/WindowsAppRuntime_BootstrapDLL/MddBootstrap.cpp#L89-L95). You can single-step through it to learn, where things go wrong.

Comment: It's a DLL; Might be that an issue ? I v'e also attached the error output log.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT the same error occurs in that SelfContained app if I call the bootstrap directly. I edited, noting that.

Comment: Could you please show a minimal, reproducible sample without private information? [I just include `<MddBootstrap.h>`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khJRv.png).

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT https://github.com/WindowsNT/wui3 . Open wui3.vcxproj and add the `<WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>true</WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>`, then compile the project. If you do not have already the WinAppSDK 1.3 installed, this does not run.

Comment: Now that I see it again, the bootstrap fails to be called but the application still runs.

Comment: In EXE, it works. When inside a DLL, it fails.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT as I see it, each time there's a build, the runtime packages are different, so I must redistribute the whole output again instead of doing so for the first EXE and then the updates reuse the same winappsdk files.. is that true?

Comment: [I don't know what you mean....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPTbM.png) Also the Win32 App.exe initializes an installed runtime not the self-contained runtime and the WinUI3 wui3.exe runs as a self-contained application well.