# Windows APP SDK using "Self-Contained" from a desktop app

Tags: winapi, winui-3

My app has two executables, one for running "normal" non WinUI3 mode and another one built as "Self Contained" (from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/package-and-deploy/self-contained-deploy/deploy-self-contained-apps)).

The "self contained" WinUI3 app runs correctly from the directory that also contains all the WinUI3 redistributables.

The first "normal" desktop app can use the [Bootstraper API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/use-windows-app-sdk-run-time#using-the-bootstrapper-api) to also use WinUI3, but only if the Windows APP SDK [redistributable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/downloads) is installed.

This redistributable has some issues occasionally, it won't install to some of my client's PC for a reason (even with -f) or won't uninstall easily.

Is there a way to make the "normal" desktop app succeed in calling the bootstrapper? No matter how I call [MddBootstrapInitialize2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/win32/mddbootstrap/nf-mddbootstrap-mddbootstrapinitialize2) it fails, but the "Self Contained" built (which is supposedly calling the same bootstrap) succeeds. Both executables are in the same folder that contains all the redist files for self-contained apps.

For example,

```
PACKAGE_VERSION pg = { WINDOWSAPPSDK_RUNTIME_VERSION_UINT64 };
const wchar_t* dll = L"Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.Bootstrap.dll";
auto hL = LoadLibrary(dll);
typedef HRESULT(__stdcall* mi)(
        UINT32 majorMinorVersion,
        PCWSTR versionTag,
        PACKAGE_VERSION minVersion);
    mi M = (mi)GetProcAddress(hL, "MddBootstrapInitialize");
    if (!M)
        return E_FAIL;
    auto hr = M(WINDOWSAPPSDK_RELEASE_MAJORMINOR, WINDOWSAPPSDK_RELEASE_VERSION_TAG_W, pg);
    return hr;
}
```

Perhaps I'm pushing it too far, but since I don't really understand why Microsoft wouldn't redistribute the APP sdk in Windows automatically, it would had helped if I can bootstrap the "normal" desktop app.

Comment: [I have pointed the issue earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76197403/winui3-self-contained-application-fails-to-run#comment134434339_76197403). Also, as I said in another thread, there are some settings which make the self-contained unpackaged application use the contained DLLs. You can [try deploying Windows App SDK runtime packages directly using PackageManager.AddPackageAsync for more control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1349511/windows-app-sdk-fails-to-install-occasionally).  Or you can submit an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues.